# Is there a way to change the speed of scrollRectToVisible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview, subclassing

Is there a way to change how quickly scrollRectToVisible animates when scrolling a UIScrollView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView scrollRectToVisible at custom speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558262/uiscrollview-scrollrecttovisible-at-custom-speed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not with public methods. The duration is fixed at 0.3 seconds.

There *is* a **private, undocumented API** to change the duration:

```
@interface UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal)
-(void)_setContentOffsetAnimationDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
@end
```

but as all undocumented API, using this will lead to rejection from AppStore.

Comment: Actually, I plan on distributing Ad Hoc, might not be a problem. Where can I find this method defined? Thanks!

Comment: @Moshe: It has to be declared manually. You can include the category above to a file that uses it.

Comment: Actually, I just called it as `[scrollView _setContentOffsetAnimationDuration:8.0]` and it worked. Just note that if you're using with NSTimer, like me, the animation duration must be larger than the interval for the timer, or it will be jumpy.

Answer (score 17):

Just set the animation argument to NO and then perform your own animation using the UIView's animation class methods.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:viewFrame animated:NO];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: This however, does not call -scrollViewDidScroll: delegate methods.

Comment: True but that was not a requirement of the question author.