# iphone - UIScrollview - scrollRectToVisible with slow animation

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm using UIScrollView and using scrollRectToVisible:animated
This is working fine for me.
But I want to scroll to a location slowly so that user can notice the effect.
Is it possible.

I'm trying the following code, but didn't succeed.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];  
[scrlView scrollRectToVisible:<<some cgrect>> animated:YES];            
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView scrollRectToVisible at custom speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558262/uiscrollview-scrollrecttovisible-at-custom-speed)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The solution is actually pretty easy. If you use `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES]` the scrollview will start it's own animation, so in order to animate with your duration you have to use `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:NO]` within your animation.

In other words: This will work.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^{ [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:NO]; } 
                 completion:NULL];
```