# Slowing down UIPageViewController paging

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want my UIPageViewController to slowly scroll to the next page when  user's finger gets up from the screen. Slower than what it is by default. And if possible, some more control over it's deceleration curve, etc.

I don't want to use [SCPageViewController](https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCPageViewController). But you can see something like the effect I'm talking about in "Plain mode" of this demo animation:

[image: Slower scroll]

I have tried getting it's underlying UIScrollView and setting its decelerationRate:

```
let scrollView = view.subviews.filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first as! UIScrollView
scrollView.decelerationRate = .normal // or .fast
```

But I can't see any effect. I've also tried to assign custom decelerationRate with:

```
UIScrollView.DecelerationRate(rawValue: 0.5)
```

It has no effect either, the decelerationRate will just resets back to what was before (.normal or .fast)

I also know that I can set a delegate for the UIScrollView, but I really don't know what to do it.

Do you know any way to achieve this effect, as simple as possible?

Comment: What if you could animate that scrolling moment some how to make slower? The following post is in Obj C but I think it might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237659/iphone-uiscrollview-scrollrecttovisible-with-slow-animation

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it might be useful but I can't think of a way to use it. Page controller does some calculations under the hood to find next/previous page position, etc. Also I don't know where to put the animation code. And how to disable default animation, without losing other benefits of UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do what you are talking about, but I think you'll need to implement your own animations by overriding/setting `UIViewController.transitioningDelegate` or `UIViewController.transitionCoordinator`. Possibly both. A search around the web should find you some blog posts on doing custom transitions that will point you in the right direction. Here's one that might be a good start https://www.raywenderlich.com/322-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started

If that doesn't help. The only other suggestion I have would be to implement your own page view controller.